# prevent files from renaming themselves automatically

Tags: bash, mac, rename, metadata, file-types

-using Mac OSX 10.14.3,

I have some script files such as this:

```
#!/opt/local/bin/bash
...do some commands in bash;
```

I use them a lot from the terminal, and want to give them short names without a `.sh` prefix

Whenever I rename them manually and remove this file suffix, after a few seconds the suffix returns.  I thought this might be Spotlight, so I transferred this folder into Spotlights 'Privacy' tab.  This at least removed a lot of the metadata of the file, but the automatic renaming of the file to include the suffix still continues.

I tried renaming the files using three methods: `mv file.sh file` and also Finder and also my text editor.  All of them appear to succeed, but after a few seconds the file reverts to the original name with a suffix.

This behaviour is seen not just in `.sh` files, but `.py` and others as well.  It is as if OSX is forcing me to keep the file extension.

By the way, I don't want simply to make the suffix invisible in Finder.  I want to remove the suffix so that I can type shorter commands at the terminal.

Comment: How did you rename the files? How long does the new name stay? Try in a bash terminal?

Comment: I have edited the question to give these details.

Comment: This very likely has nothing to do with Bash or Python. Have you tried renaming any other files?

Comment: A better way to handl the problem would be to define aliases in your shell: `alias foobar='foobar.sh'`

Comment: Mac OS X isn't doing this.  At least certainly not for me on 10.13 High Sierra.  Look for some extension/daemon/agent you have running that could be doing this for you.  Create a test acct on your Mac, log into that, and repeat the test.  If it's happening on the test acct, then it's a system-wide extension/etc, if not then it's just something in your acct, so you can try logging in in "safe" mode or whatever they call it, so if that clears it from you acct.